# Map functions returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Getting this error when running the code from below `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'update' of undefined`

item.id has a value, I have console.log it a few times. I'm not sure why I'm getting undefined.

```js
          const { data, error } = await supabase
          .from('records')
          .update({ Sample1: record.fields.Name, Sample2: record.fields.Price, Sample3: record.fields.Year, Sample4: record.fields.Location })
          .match({ id: data.map(item => {return item.id})})
          if(error) console.log(error);
```

Comment: The error means that `supabase.from('records')` returns `undefined`. Or of course the error is thrown inside one of these functions where something tries to access an `update` property.

Comment: Supabase is not returning undefined and I'm passing the correct way to update. Now I'm getting the error `Unhandled Rejection (ReferenceError): Cannot access 'data' before initialization`

Comment: That error comes from the fact that you are using `data` to generate the argument for `.match` while at the same time `data` will be populated with the *result* of calling `.match`. It should be obvious that this cannot be possible. Without any context it's difficult to help here. Maybe you are meaning to access a different `data` variable?